# What is the difference between [object property] and object.property?

Tags: objective-c

They both do the same thing, return the value of an object's property called property. So, what is the difference other than syntax? Same thing also happens with arrays,

```
[[numberArray objectAtIndex:indexInt] integerValue]
```

is the same as

```
((NSNumber*)numberArray[indexInt]).integerValue
```

At least it has been the same so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely no difference between using the dot notation or the square bracket messaging syntax. - with the caveat that you can send any message to id, but you can't get or set any property of id through dot syntax

Comment: That's almost true, with the caveat that you can send any message to `id`, but you can't get or set any property of `id` through dot syntax (As the OP's example shows, you have to cast explicitly to use dot syntax.)